# Send text message via Bluetooth to another device without connecting

Tags: react-native, mobile, bluetooth, message

Is it possible to send via Bluetooth text messages and receive from multiple devices WITHOUT having to connect to any of them?

I am mostly working with React Native.  However, if you have any idea how to do it via other frameworks, please let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try downloading bridgefy and perhaps include their API to your code. Go through their documentation. Goodluck.

Comment: it seems awesome! One thing, do users have to pair to each other to send messages or does Bridgefy do it for them?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but there is no possible way to do this. You can only send text messages via Bluetooth only if the other person's Bluetooth connection is paired with yours. You can type it in .Txt and send it via Bluetooth. However there are other means of transferring text like public network sharing.